# WCF service with dual methods - one for structured results and one for raw XML results. Is there a better way?

Tags: xml, wcf, wsdl

I'm designing a WCF web service method that can return results either as a raw XML string, or as a structure, depending on the client's preference.

A simple approach is to have two separate methods:

```
MyStructure GetData();
string GetDataAsXML();
```

This should work fine, but given that the wire representation in both cases will be the same (or at least equivalent), I'm wondering if there's a better way to represent this in the interface?   Is there an elegant way I can merge the two methods into one, for example?

Comment: Why not merely use GetData() - and then leave it to the client to decide whether they'll deserialize it or not?

Comment: The main problem with just offering GetData() is performance.  If the client wants XML, it's more efficient to just return the XML directly, rather than have the client proxy deserialize it and then have the client application serialize it back to XML again.

Comment: I second Jeremy's recommendation - just use the "MyStructure" and if the client really needs the raw XML, it can always be serialized into XML - works a lot easier, I think - and I'm not sure if it's really that big a performance hit (I doubt it - measure it first, before optimizing prematurely!)

Comment: @Dylan: it's all XML on the wire. Always. Also, I doubt you'll notice the overhead of deserialization, especially if you're using data contracts. They're quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

Umm your results will be in XML either way. One will look like this

```
<Response>
<SomeTags>
  <SomeTag />
  <SomeTag />
  <SomeTag />
</SomeTags>
</Response>
```

And the other will look like this

```
<Response>
<Data>
   &lt;SomeTags&gt;
      &lt;SomeTag /&gt;
      &lt;SomeTag /&gt;
      &lt;SomeTag /&gt;
   &lt;/SomeTags&gt;
</Data>
</Response>
```

I'd just stick with the first and let your clients figure out how they want to parse the information.